# Extending UserCreationForm to include email, first name, and last name

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

I've been stuck on this for a while now and can't seem to figure out what's going on. I'm just starting to learn Django and I got my login set up and now want to implement a registration page.

I used the UserCreationForm form at first and that worked fine, but I want to add fields for Email, First name, and Last name. I figured I could just subclass UserCreationForm and add the fields but that doesn't seem to work. Also I tried overriding the save method, but it still doesn't work.

My custom form looks like this:

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=75)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("first_name", "last_name", "email",)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data["first_name"]
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data["last_name"]
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

The view to handle this is the following:

```
def Register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save();
            new_user = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password1'])
            login(request, new_user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/members/home')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()

    return render_to_response('register.html', {'form' : form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The form loads just fine with the new fields and everything, but when I submit I get the error:

```
AttributeError at /register/

'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'backend'
```

Oh, and also I'm using Django 1.3.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Another thing I should mention is that it appears the record is being entered into the database just fine, except the username field is empty... first_name, last_name, email, and password all have values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that your meta class `fields` doesn't include `username`.

You are inheriting the form field from `UserCreationForm` but it's not saving to the `User` model and therefore `authenticate` is failing, and crashing on `login()`

The docs suggest you check whether `authenticate()` is successful before using `login()`

Comment: That worked! Thank you! I'm not 100% sure I fully understand though. Why do I have to specify the username field but not the password field?

Comment: Because passwords are set via `user.set_password`, not some `ModelForm` specific logic.

Comment: Oh, right, that makes sense. Thanks again, I really appreciate it.