# 'User' object has no attribute 'backend'

Tags: django, forms

**EDIT:** If you want to skip the background story and just check the error message and code dump it's all at the bottom :)

---

I've been trying to implement a user-registration form for half a day now and feel that I'm sooo close but not quite there yet.

So I started out by implementing Django's built in `UserCreationForm`. And for my view I cunstructed this piece of code inspired by a response to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287485/taking-user-input-to-create-users-in-django):

```py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login 

def create_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = User.objects.create_user(**form.cleaned_data)
            login(new_user)
            return redirect('post_list')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()

    return render(request, 'blog/create_user.html', {'form': form})
```

Problem was: I wanted the users to be able to store their email as well. So I decided to use a piece of code from this [blog](http://jessenoller.com/blog/2011/12/19/quick-example-of-extending-usercreationform-in-django) to extend the `UserCreationForm()` in the `forms.py` file:

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreateForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

It still refused to include the email-part when I checked the actual web-page (even after I switched out: `from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm` to `from .forms import UserCreationForm`). Finally I switched names in my forms.py file to UserForm in both the `views.py` and the `forms.py` files. So in the `forms.py` file it now said:

```py
class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
```

Solution inspired by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910769/extending-usercreationform-to-include-email-first-name-and-last-name).

So now it said `'password1' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`, I thought "of course, I'm passing a dictionary from my form into create_user and now that I've tampered with `UserCreationForm` it doesn't run as smoothly any more: create_user wants to have a username, email and password right? But now I'm sending username, email, password1 and password2.

So I added the following to the code in `views.py`:

```py
if form.is_valid():
    username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
    email = form.cleaned_data["email"]
    password = form.cleaned_data["password1"]
    new_user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
    login(new_user)
```

So now I get `TypeError at /create_user/: login() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)` and what really grinds my gears is how this wasn't an issue before I tampered with `UserCreationForm` (to the best of my recollection). But alright, alright, I'll google it, read through the documentation and some examples, looks like most people call the login-function with `login(request, user)` so I change my code again to:

```py
new_user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
login(request, new_user)
```

And here, I'm finally at an impasse as I get:

```
'User' object has no attribute 'backend'
```

I google it and either I don't find anything that correlates with my situation or I'm to slow witted to see that it does. If there's anyone out there who can explain what's wrong I would greatly appreciate it.

**Code dump of current code:**
Omitted other views and unrelated imports for readability

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UserForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import login

def create_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
            email = form.cleaned_data["email"]
            password = form.cleaned_data["password1"]
            new_user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
            login(new_user)
            return redirect('post_list')
    else:
        form = UserForm()

    return render(request, 'blog/create_user.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in):

> Calling authenticate() first
>
> When you’re manually logging a user in, you must successfully
>   authenticate the user with authenticate() before you call login().
>   authenticate() sets an attribute on the User noting which
>   authentication backend successfully authenticated that user (see the
>   backends documentation for details), and this information is needed
>   later during the login process. An error will be raised if you try to
>   login a user object retrieved from the database directly.

So, in order to log in a user, you must first call `authenticate()` and check if a user is returned:

```
new_user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
new_user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if new_user:
    login(request, new_user)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to call authenticate() on the user before you call login(). This will check if a user is returned and won't allow you to call the user from the database directly. The code snippet should work on your cleaned data.

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login 

def create_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = User.objects.create_user(**form.cleaned_data)
            new_user = authenticate(**form.cleaned_data)
            login(request, new_user)
            return redirect('post_list')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()

    return render(request, 'blog/create_user.html', {'form': form})
```